# Pluralization issue in "helpful flags" text in profile activity summary page, when there is only one helpful flag

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, plurals

When a user only has one helpful flag that they've cast, the number of helpful flags in their profile shows as "1 helpful flags":

[image: 1 helpful flags]

It should show "flag", not "flags", if the user's only cast one helpful flag.